# PHP: Passing an array item that not exist by reference adds it as null

Tags: php, arrays, variables, reference

we've found a behavior that we don't know if it's right or not.

Please, view the next code:

```
<?php
$a = [];
$b = [];
$a[] = 'Hello';
$b[] = 'Bye';
if (isset($b[1]))
{
  $b1 = $b[1];
}
$a1 = defaultValue($a[1], 'again');
print_r($a);
print_r($b);
exit;
function defaultValue(&$var, $val)
{
  return isset($var) ? $var : $val;
}
```

The result was:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Hello
    [1] =>
)
Array
(
    [0] => Bye
)
```

Why the item $a[1] was created? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing $var into DefaultValue as reference (the & sign).
This is place where $a[1] is created and set to null.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php

Answer (score 1):

It's explained in the manual:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatdo.php

> Note:
>   If you assign, pass, or return an undefined variable by reference, it will get created.

So, when you pass an undefined reference, it'll be created as null. Isset ensures that should be set and different of null. So the value "again" is returned.

Comment: Thanks. I've look for in the manual, obviously not with the right terms.

Comment: Thankis @gabriel-heming

Comment: @jhernandis You're welcome. That isn't a common knowledge.